# Displaying related records in popup using ArcGIS JavaScript API?

Tags: popup, relates, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am attempting to display related fields in a popup window.  I've created a GraphicsLayer, consisting of features from the results of a QueryTask.  Upon adding the features to the GraphicsLayer, I am assigning a popupTemplate to each feature:

```
var popupTemplate = {
  title: "<b>{LONGNAME}</b>",
  content: [{
    type: "fields",
    fieldInfos: [{
      fieldName: "SPACEID",
      label: "Space Identifier",
      visible: true
    },{
      fieldName: "relationships/1/VERTICALORDER",
      label: "Vertical Order",
      visible: true
    }]
  }]
};
```

However, [this technique](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-PopupTemplate.html#fields) does not seem to be able to reference the related table. The [SPACEID] field value is visible, but the related field value is not. Am I doing something wrong, or is there a different way to accomplish this?

EDIT: Perhaps this [functionality is not possible yet](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/220072/how-to-retrieve-data-from-a-related-table-by-using-arcgis-javascript-api-4-1)?  I've tested this with a simple FeatureLayer, and the relationship is not honored.

```
var layer = new FeatureLayer({
    url: baseURL + "/2",
    popupTemplate: {  // autocasts as new PopupTemplate()
        title: "<b>{LONGNAME}</b>",
        content: [{
            type: "fields",
            fieldInfos: [{
                fieldName: "SPACEID",
                label: "Space Identifier",
                visible: true
            },{
                fieldName: "relationships/3/FIRSTNAME",
                label: "Employee Name",
                visible: true
            }]
        }]
    }
});
```

I have verified the relationship is functioning, using the REST queryRelatedRecords window.  However the FeatureLayer does not see the table.  Is there something further that needs to be done?  I should note that the service is a MapService, in case that matters.

This issue is discussed [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/127661/popup-with-related-tables?rq=1) and [elsewhere](https://community.esri.com/thread/104992).

Answer (score 0):

`fieldName: "relationships/1/VERTICALORDER"` means that have created a second *RelationShip* in your *GraphicLayer*.

If you didn't, (otherwise you would have post the code) then you have two options :

- build a RelationQuery https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-tasks-support-RelationshipQuery.html to add its results to your features, so you'll get a new field `VERTICALORDER`
- build a RelationShip https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-support-Relationship.html to your GraphicLayer

Comment: I have a relationship for the MapService layer from which the features used to create the GraphicLayer came from.  The GraphicLayer doesn't, as far as I can tell, have any relationships.  Can you elaborate on how one would create a new relationship?